# gstreamer not flushing to the filesink

Tags: gstreamer

I have this gstreamer pipeline which works from the coomand line as:

```
gst-launch-1.0 autovideosrc ! tee name = t ! queue ! omxh264enc ! 
'video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream' ! h264parse ! qtmux 
! filesink name=fileSink location=test.mp4 t. ! queue ! videoscale ! 
video/x-raw, width=480,height=270 ! xvimagesink name=displaySink -e
```

Now, I am replicating this on the C++ side as follows:

```
GstElement * pipeline = gst_parse_launch("autovideosrc ! tee name = t ! "
                    "queue ! omxh264enc ! video/x-h264, "
                    "stream-format=(string)byte-stream ! h264parse ! "
                    "qtmux ! filesink name=fileSink location=test.mp4 t. "
                    "! queue ! videoscale ! video/x-raw, width=480,height=270 ! "
                    "xvimagesink name=displaySink", &error);</raw>
```

I connect this to a QT window and play as follows:

```
GstElement * displaySink = gst_bin_get_by_name (GST_BIN (pipeline), "displaySink");
qDebug() << displaySink;
// prepare the ui
QWidget window;
window.resize(480, 270);
window.show();

WId xwinid = window.winId();
gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle (GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(displaySink), xwinid);

// run the pipeline
qDebug() << "Calling run...";

GstStateChangeReturn sret = gst_element_set_state (pipeline,
                                                   GST_STATE_PLAYING);
if (sret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);
    // Exit application
    QTimer::singleShot(0, QApplication::activeWindow(), SLOT(quit()));
}

int ret = app.exec();

window.hide();
gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
gst_object_unref (pipeline);
```

This starts displaying the video stream onto my Qt window and the file `test.mp4` gets created and it starts to grow in size. However, when I quit the application, the file is not playable. I have a feeling this is because the last bits or some header information is not written due to me calling:

```
gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
```

I am speculating that this perhaps closes the pipeline without ensuring that the file is correctly created and finalized. Is there a way to ensure that EOF or EOS is called on the pipeline before closing and ensuring that the file is written properly? This is also a speculation at the moment from my part but something else could be wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes sending EOS is necessary..

So before the NULLing of pipe do:

```
gst_element_send_event(pipeline, gst_event_new_eos());
```

---

**Edit** for checking if EOS passed:

According to [documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstevent.html?gi-language=c#gst_event_new_eos):

> The EOS event will travel down to the sink elements in the pipeline which will then post the GST_MESSAGE_EOS on the bus after they have finished playing any buffered data.

This means that to check if the EOS event successfully passed through the pipeline you could add bus watch callback with [gst_bus_add_watch](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstbus.html?gi-language=c#gst_bus_add_watch) and check there for GST_MESSAGE_EOS.

Comment: How to know that the EOS has been processed by the filesink? It still generates broken files when it's set to NULL in the handler of `MESSAGE_EOS`.

Comment: @Velkan just enable GST_DEBUG=5 when running your app.. there is some debug category for this but I do not remember.. you should see eos event going through pipe.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but, for this to actually work, I also had to add a time delay after sending the `eos` signal, before setting the pipeline's state to `null`

Comment: @nsrCodes you could add busWatch, check for the EOS event received on the bus, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62833485/3876138) it should be received after (all) the sinks received it