# Proper way to send an EOS signal in GStreamer and receive it using C

Tags: c, gstreamer

I'm working on a C program which takes data from a file chunk by chunk and sends it into appsrc object. This part of code works great, but I want use EOS signal. So, I tried different ways, but I can't catch EOS anyway.

**First of all we need to configure GstBus for acquiring different messages**

```
_bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (_pipeline));
_bus_watch_id = gst_bus_add_watch (_bus, bus_call, this);
gst_object_unref(_bus);
```

Handler function:

```
gboolean bus_call (GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, Session* user_data) {
    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {

        case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
            g_print ("End of stream\n");
            break;

        case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR: {
            gchar  *debug;
            GError *error;

            gst_message_parse_error (msg, &error, &debug);
            g_free (debug);
            g_printerr ("Error: %s\n", error->message);
            g_error_free (error);
            break;
        }
        default:
            g_print("got message %s\n", gst_message_type_get_name (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)));
            break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Handler takes all message types, except EOS. Any suggestions?

**After that I tried to send EOS message**

There are two different ways: from appsrc and using *gst_element_send_event* function.

**First one**

```
gboolean push_data(Session *) {
    if(!_stream_alive) {
        GstFlowReturn ret;
        g_signal_emit_by_name(_appsrc, "end-of-stream", &ret);

        if (GST_FLOW_OK != ret) {
            g_print("Error occurred! EOS signal cannot be sent!\n\r");
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    push_data_all();

    return TRUE;
}
```

**Second one**

```
if (_pipeline != nullptr) {
        gboolean res = gst_element_send_event(_pipeline, gst_event_new_eos());
        if(!res) {
            g_print("Error occurred! EOS signal cannot be sent!\n\r");
        }
    }
```

So, in any case, I'm not getting EOS in my handler function. Any suggestions?

**Pipeline**

```
appsrc name=appsrc do-timestamp=true ! identity silent=false ! video/x-vp8 ! rtpvp8pay mtu=1400 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=VP8 ! webrtcbin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`appsrc` comes with its own API for that. Check documentation for `gst_app_src_end_of_stream()`.

Also keep in mind that the bus will only receive an EOS after *all* sinks are EOS. Since you didn't reveal your pipeline we cannot say anything if that may be a problem or not..

Comment: Florian, thank you very much for the reply! I added my pipeline to the original post. I hope it will help you to understand my problem.

Comment: I made simple application with **gst_app_src_end_of_stream** function and it works perfect. I'm getting an EOS signal, but when I added same code to my application I've had same problem as before. I'm not sure, but I think than problem in **webrtcbin** element.